# Why does a simple left join need a sort in the execution plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I have simple left join query like this

```
select 
    o.orderreference,   
    c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName as Customer,
    c.phone as CustomerPhoneNumber,
    case when(isjson(c.metafields) > 0) then
        JSON_VALUE(c.metafields,'$.BaseLocation')
    else
        ''
    end BaseLocation,
    case when(isjson(c.metafields) > 0) then
        JSON_VALUE(c.metafields,'$.CostCenter')
    else
        ''
    end CostCenter,
    c.email as Email,
    c.AcceptsMarketing,
    outlets.Name outletname,
    registers.name registername,
    concat(concat(users.firstname,' '), users.LastName) cashiername,
    concat(concat(ser.firstname,' '), ser.LastName) servername
from orders o with(index(test))
left join customers c
    on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
left join users 
    on users.UserId = o.CashierId
left join users ser
    on ser.UserId = o.serverid
left join outlets
    on outlets.outletid = o.OutletId
left join registers
    on registers.RegisterId = o.RegisterId
where orderdate between '2019-07-01' and '2019-07-30'
```

and the result of the execution plan have sort when orders join to customers. I want the execution plan don't need the sort is there any solution / why there is a sort there?

[image]

Here is the index test

```
create nonclustered index test on orders ([orderdate])
include (
    [customerid], [OutletId],[OrderNumber],[OrderReference],[ServerId],[CashierId],[RegisterId])
```

Comment: show your `test` index

Comment: @RoMEoMusTDiE I have edited my question, adding the index test

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I have edited the index ```test``` add the customerid in the include, the order become index seek and then still sort before joining to customers table

Comment: The test index is sorted by `orderdate`, the other columns are along for the ride in leaf data but don't form part of the index key. Does it avoid the Sort node if instead you index on `([orderdate], [customerid])` instead?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I try your solution but the sort still there

Comment: The query planner must think it's cheaper to use a table scan + sort than to use this index. Perhaps statistics are out of date or inaccurate?

Comment: @siride true the query planner think it is cheaper when the table index scan but when the data get bigger it will cause trouble, that is why I want the table to be index seek but then appear sort node

Comment: When the data gets bigger, the query planner will probably adjust the query. Keyword is "probably". I've seen SQL Server get stupid when crossing data thresholds. Worse comes to worse, you can use an index hint.

Comment: @siride agree with you, sometimes SQL Server choose more worse process when executing query and I also force the query to use my index so I think it will 100% getting worse if the plan didn't do as I want. I think the only solution is only look for another way

Comment: "why there is a sort there"? Because SQL Server has decided to do a merge join and that requires the inputs to be sorted by a key. One side is already sorted but it needs to sort the other

Comment: @MartinSmith so because SQL Server decided to do a merge join that is why there is a sort node? then is there any way to make SQL not do a merge join and choose another type of join in my case?

Comment: Actually Martin makes a good point. Your index is keyed by orderdate, but it needs to sort by CustomerId. If the index was keyed by orderdate, it wouldn't need the sort. I'm not sure that would be a good index though.